# How to make certain fields of a locked record editable?

Tags: permissions

I have a requirement where I need to make a couple of fields editable by a certain type of user (Say, Direct Sales) after the concerned record (say, Quote) is locked by an approval process.

I opened up the concerned fields from the field-level security but that doesn't make the fields editable after the record is locked.

The other solution I was exploring was setting the Modify All flag in object permissions by going to Setup > Profiles > Direct Sales.

Is there a way of doing this or is it not possible?

Comment: `Modify All Data` is not a good option for users in a profile like `Direct Sales` - opens up way too many fields that can be altered

Comment: I've used Modify All for this purpose on occasion, but like cropredy says, it's quite a broad permission (although Modify All on an object is not as bad as the global Modify All Data). You have to make sure that you cover all restrictions by using validation rules or apex triggers. And of course, sharing goes out the window when you use Modify All.

Answer (score 2):

A locked record is basically no longer editable, except possibly by an admin or by the current assigned approver (see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.approvals_create_recordeditability.htm&type=5)

So if you want anybody else to be able to edit the record, you will have to (temporarily) unlock it, or wait until it is approved or rejected.

Unlocking is possible via APEX, or more recently it has been made possible via Flows too, e.g. using this set of components: https://englhardconsulting.com/flow-and-lightning-components-package/

Of course unlocking the record is tricky, as other users might go in and edit the record at the same time. But you could create a Screen Flow that allows editing just those fields and then build in apex actions when the screen flow progresses. Somewhat like this:

1. load the record
2. allow the user to enter new field values on the flow screen
3. unlock the record
4. update the record with the entries made in the screen flow
5. lock the record

This should prevent any other user from jumping in and editing the record, as actions 3-4-5 will be executed one after another.
You can define who can do this by making the Flow available to only those users/profiles.

Comment: Hm... I'm new to salesforce and this seems like a lot of work :)